# Binding models to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to Bind two models (say ModelA and ModelB classes) to a view.ascx page. And each of these classes have List objects that I would like to access in view. I know we can access one class by associating strongly typed model to one of the classes. How do I bind the other class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a **ViewModel** - class containing all models you need (in this case ModelA and ModelB). Then bind the view to this ViewModel and access it like `model.ModelA.Property` in your view.

Edit: You wrote that both ModelA and modelB has their collections? So you create something like:

```
public class ABViewModel
{
    public ModelA A {get;set;}
    public ModelB B {get;set;}
}
```

Then instantiate it in controller like:

```
ABViewModel abvm = new ABViewModel();
abvm.A = new ModelA();
abvm.B = new ModelB();
```

And return your view (strongly typed to ABViewModel).

```
return View(abvm);
```

And access your properties in View:

```
foreach (var item in model.A.CollectionProperty) // something like this
```

Or

```
model.B.Property // something like this
```

Ie. you can access both .. ModelA and ModelB, because they are now properties of another object - your new model.

Note: I am not sure, if you use `model.` or `Model.` in mvc2 to acces your model. It's `model` in mvc3.

Answer (score 2):

You write a third class wrapping those two lists:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<Foo> List1 { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then you use this class as a view model passed to the view. Then inside the view you can access both lists:

```
<% foreach(var item in Model.List1) { %>
    ...
<% } %>

<% foreach(var item in Model.List2) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```